# Add "TODO" when I scheduled a stuck item

Tags: emacs, org-mode

How can emacs automatically add "TODO" 
when I use C-c C-s or C-c C-d to schedule/deadline one Item.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do that:

```
(defadvice org-schedule (after add-todo activate)
  (org-todo "TODO"))

(defadvice org-deadline (after add-todo activate)
  (org-todo "TODO"))
```